# Tree-based directory browser?

Tags: dired, directories

I love dired, but sometimes (particularly when filming screencasts) I want to see the tree-structure of a directory and its children, a la the tree(1) command. Is there a tree-oriented directory browser for Emacs?

Comment: Pretty sure ecb can do this.

Comment: @EdgarAroutiounian If that's the case, I recommend making an answer out of it :)

Comment: Although it isn't a *folding* tree filemanager, I would recommend [ranger.el](https://github.com/ralesi/ranger.el)! If you don't like the [Miller columns](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Miller_columns) you can easily switch to [minimal ranger mode (deer)](https://github.com/ralesi/ranger.el#minimal-ranger-mode-deer).

Answer (score 27, accepted):

Additionally you can use [dired-subtree](https://github.com/Fuco1/dired-hacks/blob/master/dired-subtree.el) from [dired-hacks](https://github.com/Fuco1/dired-hacks) repo.

Here you have short [demo](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=z26b8HKFsNE) and screenshot from my setup where I press `i` to drill down folder and `;` to go back.:

```
  (define-key dired-mode-map "i" 'dired-subtree-insert)
  (define-key dired-mode-map ";" 'dired-subtree-remove)
```

[image: dired-subtree]

PS
I'm also aware of [direx](https://github.com/m2ym/direx-el) which looks like that: [image: direx]:

Comment: I've tried dired-subtree but the tree structure wasn't as visually apparent as I was looking for. Direx looks perfect tho, I'm gonna go try it.

Comment: I'm this one because the suggestion of Direx looks ideal for my use case of putting a directory tree visualization front and center. That's not to discount @keelerm's excellent suggestions though.

Comment: You can get equivalent functionality using one key binding: (define-key dired-mode-map "i" 'dired-subtree-toggle). I like to map it to "C-c i" though since dired also does insert subdirectory using "i".

Answer (score 25):

There are a couple of options for this.

You can check out [dirtree](https://github.com/zk/emacs-dirtree), which is based on dired.

There is also an emacs port of vim's NERDTree called [neotree](https://github.com/jaypei/emacs-neotree).

Both are excellent packages, though I tend to favor neotree as it has convenient bindings to let me create and delete files and directories.  I do not believe dirtree has this support, though I could be wrong.  It has been a while since I last used it.

Comment: Thanks, while direx looks to be ideal for my immediate need, you've reminded me that I need to spend some time with neotree.

Answer (score 19):

Have you ever tried Emacs' `M-x speedbar`? :-) before installing some new package I'd try an inbuilt solution...

Update 2020-01-10

Actually I'm using now [dired-sidebar](https://github.com/jojojames/dired-sidebar) which is available via Melpa.

Comment: …and one more upvote for suggesting a builtin.

Answer (score 11):

You can invoke `dired` with an argument, ie. <kbd>C-u C-x d</kbd> and after prompting for the directory it will also let you modify the switches passed to `ls`. Add `R` and `dired` will recursively list all sub-directories, each in it's own section.

If you only want to see the contents of some sub-directories, press <kbd>i</kbd> when the point is on a directory name.

You can also use the `find-dired` command, with or without switches. Instead of showing sub-directories in their own section it prints the full path of each file. You can toggle showing file details with <kbd>(</kbd> so that the long paths fit horizontally on screen.

These are all built-in.

Answer (score 4):

There is also [ztree](https://github.com/fourier/ztree). I use it when I need to take a look at directory structure, although usually I use vanilla Dired for all other things.

Answer (score 3):

[Treemacs](https://github.com/Alexander-Miller/treemacs) works. It allows you to have a treelike structure.

Comment: Is this an answer or a question (two questions)? It is pretty-much a link-only answer, if it is an answer. As such, it risks being deleted. See https://emacs.stackexchange.com/help/how-to-ask.

Comment: @Drew, fwiw I think this is just a language/interpretation issue. Treemacs is an absolutely acceptable suggestion to the OP's question.

Answer (score 1):

Take a look at [sidebar.el](https://github.com/sebastiencs/sidebar.el).

As the repo said, it is is a customizable file explorer with git integration, but not only that. You can also get the list of buffers and your maildirs with mu4e.

[image]