# How to show other files and subdirectories in current dired file buffer?

Tags: dired

If I open dired buffer with filename as parameter, and not directory, only that one file is displayed in dired mode. But I wish I could open dired buffer like that `(dired "/usr/bin/pwd")` and see not only one `pwd` entry, but all other files and subdirectories, and cursor will be on `pwd`.

That is the default behavior of `dired-jump`, and I wish I could somehow do the same for ordinary filepath, and not current buffer.

Comment: Check out https://emacs.stackexchange.com/questions/413/tree-based-directory-browser

Answer (score 3):

`C-h f dired-jump` tells us:

> **`dired-jump`** is an interactive autoloaded compiled Lisp function in
>   `dired-x.el`.
>
> It is bound to `C-x C-j`.
>
> `(dired-jump &optional OTHER-WINDOW FILE-NAME)`
>
> Jump to Dired buffer corresponding to current buffer.
>
> If in a file, Dired the current directory and move to file’s line.
>
> If in Dired already, pop up a level and goto old directory’s line.
>
> In case the proper Dired file line cannot be found, refresh the dired
>   buffer and try again.
>
> When `OTHER-WINDOW` is non-`nil`, jump to Dired buffer in other window.
>
> **When `FILE-NAME` is non-`nil`, jump to its line in Dired.**
>
> **Interactively with prefix argument, read `FILE-NAME`.**

So you can get what you request using `C-u M-x dired-jump` or just `C-u C-x C-j`.

If you don't want to hit `C-u` each time, you can define your own command that does the same thing without hitting `C-u`:

```el
(defun my-dired-jump (&optional other-window file)
  "..."
  (interactive (list nil (read-file-name "Jump to Dired file: ")))
  (dired-jump other-window file))
```